# Netflix Desktop in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: ppa

I have been trying to install Netflix desktop in ubuntu 18.10 and not succeeding with the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

I am getting the following error.

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Please help

Comment: Try opening that PPA in a web browser, navigate to the 'dists' folder, and look for the  'cosmic' packages, and you will discover the answer.

Comment: @Jay (E.G. "18.10 doesn't have netflix app yet, only 18.04 and under does") why don't you try the web app on google chrome? that's what I do.

Comment: 18.10 will not have a netflix app; Not any newer releases. Netflix changed to a format we can not use. There is no need too: this app installs wine and all the issues with it. Netflix works with firefox directly from Ubuntu. Only thing we then can not is watch offline.

Comment: @Rinzwind consider converting your comment to an answer. :D